# Cross-Origin Request Blocked error on sending post to an api using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hi i have an like this https://rdkportal.ccp.xcal.tv/build_images/cdl on sending a post request to it i will be able to get some information in json as response.
This is the format for sending it using linux

```
curl -u username:password https://rdkportal.ccp.xcal.tv/build_images/cdl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST -d '{"image_name": "MX011AN_VBN_master_20160118234003sdy_NG", "recipients_list": "some_user@.com", "cdl": "PROD", "type": "tftp", "stb": { "ip4_address": "0.0.0.0", "ip6_address": "2001:558:4030:2:96d4:feff:fe7c:7500", "mac_address": "", "serial_number": "" }}'
```

I was success full in sending a POST request and receiving the response by executing the above curl command in a linux machine.

I am trying to do similar thing in javascript using ajax but i am getting the below error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://rdkportal.ccp.xcal.tv/build_images/cdl. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Here's my code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://rdkportal.ccp.xcal.tv/build_images/cdl',
        crossDomain: true,
        data: '{"some":"json"}',
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var value = responseData.someKey;
            alert('POST success');
        },
        error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('POST failed.');
        }
    });
```

I also dont know how to send the credentials with the request in ajax. Please help i am strucked up here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `rdkportal.ccp.xcal.tv` even allow cross origin requests

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the server/endpoint.  If you own it, then you can.  If not, you're screwed.

Comment: i am not sure about it. How to check that ??

Comment: The server doesn't allow CORS

Comment: `This system is solely for the use of authorized Comcast personnel` - if you're using the system legitimately, you wouldn't need to ask such questions

Comment: i am authorised person only i have the credentials for it as well

Comment: The server is maintained by some other team i will check with them whether it will allow cors. If its allowing how to send post request to it.

Comment: you need to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin or some other headers from the server..more details here https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: check this also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acheive these things in 3 ways:

1) You can install chrome plugin if server side code is not in your control means you guys are not handling it.

Link:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

2). You can create proxy server and communicate using those new urls/api.

3). The 3rd and last and best is to allow Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to either *(for giving access to all urls from any domain ), or Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 'your system ip if running locally else hostname' (for giving access to only that particular host)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the header to allow requests from other places into the endpoint.

"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

This sends the header with the authorised domains who can make requests to this endpoint, (* means all).

CORS expects to know if you are authorised to make requests on that server, so sending it on the header resolves that problem.

How to add this on the header depends on the language are you using (node php ruby java).

If you elaborate on the backend i can help you.

Comment: Also note, this doesn't work without a webserver set up

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following header to the request:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: root-url-here.com
```

But **most importantly**, the server needs to send this header back in the response with the identical URL (e.g root-url-here.com).

If you are not the developer of the server side, you should ask them to add your request URL to the list of accepted request origins.

Comment: its better to be specific about the Origin in this header instead of a * which allows all origins.